# GNU ARM ECLIPSE newest release does support ARM7TDMI architecture or not?

Tags: arm, embedded, gnu

I have installed latest version of GNU ARM eclipse which support Cortex series.

I have to write code for old ARM architecture which is ARM7TDMI.

Could any one guide me what changes needs to be done to work on ARM7.

Comment: Basically, download gcc toolchain, check support of ARM7TDMI and ARM7 in this toolchain. Use correct compilation options to generate the compatible code. This is all always a bit tricky and if you don't use one of the mainstream processors like cortex-M4, googling may be complicated. 
Here a link for determination of architecture support that helped me a lot in the past : https://answers.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+question/193998

Comment: @Julien. Thanks for your valuable time and kind reply. Latest gcc toolchain will not work for ARM7TDMI? Can you tell me which particular version should i download?

Answer (score 0):

GCC 7.3 should support the ARM7TDMI says the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/ARM-Options.html#ARM-Options).

But it depends on how it has been compiled.  So I just used `arm-none-eabi-gcc --print-multi-lib` on the latest [arm-none-eabi-gcc](https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads) build and it does not support this old ARMv4 architecture.

I think you should rebuild GCC from sources to have support for ARMv4 (ARM7TDMI). Even if this architecture is deprecated (see documentation)